# Docker не устанавливается

Tags: docker, установка

Пытался скачать Doker, вроде установился, но при запуске каждый раз выдавал критическую ошибку, удалил его - удалив все файлы с названием Doker в двух папках в Program Files и в AppData , в итоге при запуске загрузчика докер устанавливается за секунду и пишет что он якобы обновился, нету ни приложения, ни файлов докера.[image: Что пишет установщик Doker] ] может есть возможн

Comment: если в терминале написать `docker` - что выдает?

Comment: привет, сори за игнор "docker" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом